# can you access soap xml's in SQL and parse it in XQuery without the use of CLR?

Tags: sql, sqlclr, xquery-sql

as the title suggests, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

At a superficial level yes, it is possible. But would you want to re-implement in SQL the entire SOAP stack to validate the message for [ws-security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security), [ws-metadatexchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-MetadataExchange), [ws-addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Addressing), [ws-reliablemessaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-ReliableMessaging) and what else?

Is this a good job for sqlclr? Absolutely not. Why would sqlclr have to handle the transport and enveloping of a message? This should be handled close to where the message is accepted, way before it gets written into the database.

So let WCF handle the SOAP layer, that's one thing is actually *good* at. There is no reason why the database layer should end up with the entire SOAP package.

Comment: hi Remus, can you provide me an example on how to access xml through Soap URL such as this? http://www2a.cdc.gov/nip/IIS/IISStandards/XML.asp?rpt=mvx